# Chrome bug? New line wraps the next element

Tags: css

I think theoretically raw new line in html should not be rendered, or affect the layout anyway, but i Chrome seems like it does:
http://jsfiddle.net/tzhong/4Nhb7/2/

The link works fine in Firefox and IE(only have 10 tested), but not in Chrome and Safari.

Is this a known WebKit bug?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left">Left</div>
<div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
<p></p>

<div class="container">
<div class="left">Left</div><div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.right {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}


.container {
    margin-top: 120px;
    background-color: rgb(83, 86, 90);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Chances of something being wrong with your code > chances of there being a Chrome bug

Comment: I have no doubt on that, but Firefox works, so I have to pick a hero here.

Answer (score 2):

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

`inline-block` elements add whitespace between elements if there is space in the html.

With the elements set to `display: inline-block`, this will cause whitespace to appear.

```
<div class="left">Left</div>
<div class="right">Right</div>
```

Your second set of code is one fix - remove the whitespace between elements:

```
<div class="left">Left</div><div class="right">Right</div>
```

Which can also be done with comments like so:

```
<div class="left">Left</div><!--
--><div class="right">Right</div>
```

Or, probably the best solution is using `font-size: 0` on the parent element, then resetting the font-size on the children, with a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Wmmq/)**:

```
.container {font-size: 0;}
.left, .right {font-size: 16px;}
```

I looked at this in Firefox, and if you take `float: right` off `.right`, there is space in the first set of elements. So it appears that Firefox needs `display: inline-block` set on more than one element to create that extra whitespace.

Comment: Jap. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nhb7/3/) See the space because of my space in the HTML. Use float on both divs instead and it is fixed :)

Comment: thanks @brouxhaha for the link. I guess Firefox starts ignoring the spacing between inline-blocks.

Comment: Add more context to your answer