# No Whitespace w/divs and No Set Width

Tags: html, css

I am redoing my website and have run into an issue. When I use the tabs as `<div>` elements, I am getting white space in between them. You can use [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GameShank/2e7cj/). I have found some of this question on the site, but they all require a width change.

Some of my tabs will be very long, so I would love to not use a set width. Is there any way to do this using only HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is similar to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249964/chrome-bug-new-line-wraps-the-next-element/20250026#20250026)**, even though that one is using `display: inline-block`.

If you set `#topnav` to `font-size: 0`, the whitespace will go away and nothing else will change because you have a font-size set on the child elements.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the white-space issue, you should not use the `display:inline` property. You should use floats like this:

```
float:left
```

**EDIT**
Other solution with less html and css manipulation : you could use the solution described on [this article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

```
<center>
        <div id="topnav">
            <span class="tabb">Home</span><!--
            --><span class="tabr">Arcade</span><!--
            --><span class="tabg">Support</span>
        </div>
</center>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2e7cj/6/)**

Comment: Is there a way to center it with the float property?